# RubyGems: no such file to load using mp3info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mp3, id3, id3lib

I'm trying to read the duration out of an mp3 file using [ruby-mp3info](http://ruby-mp3info.rubyforge.org/) and my test.rb file currently looks like this:

```
require "rubygems"
require "mp3info"

# read and display infos & tags
Mp3Info.open("audiofile.mp3") do |mp3info|
  puts mp3info
end
```

However, when I run `ruby test.rb` I get the error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- mp3info (LoadError)
```

I'm on a Mac running Snow Leopard, and other that running `sudo gem install ruby-mp3info` this is a pretty basic install. id3lib-ruby looks like a possible alternative, however the Mac install seems a bit more involved.

Is there an easy way to fix the mp3info install or otherwise get the duration of an mp3 file?

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `gem install ruby-mp3info` without the sudo.

Comment: When you run with sudo, it looks for your ruby gems in the root directory. Caused me tons of headaches. :(

Comment: Yes, i know what you mean. The "sudo problem" is another reason to use rvm in my opinion.